# Confirm From Email Error in Configure Event

Tags: civievent

I get this error while in the Configure Event -> Online Registration tab and trying to enable the Send Confirmation Email feature:

Warning: idn_to_ascii() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given in /home2/nymissionary/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Rule/Email.php on line 58

A screenshot is shown below. I need your help so I can use this feature.

~ Ron

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this issue has been reported and fixed here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1469

With this patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/271.patch

To apply.

First make up a backup of the file.

Then option one - if you have command line access you would want to

navigate to

/home2/nymissionary/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/

Download the patch using wget

wget https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/271.patch

This will create a file called 271.patch

Then you want to apply the patch using the patch command

patch -p1 < 271.patch

( What this does

1. use the patch command
2. strip off the first 1 bit of the path when searching for the files (in this case the a and the b from a/HTML/QuickForm/Rule/Email.php b/HTML/QuickForm/Rule/Email.php )
3. and read in the file you downloaded to get the instructions on what to do.

)

In this case it looks like a pretty simple patch that you could do manually if you were more comfortable.

Again make a backup of the file then edit the file: HTML/QuickForm/Rule/Email.php

Then look at 
https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/271.patch

What you want to do is add any line (without the +) that starts with a plus and remove anything with a minus.

You want to add the code between the lines without the pluses above and below so the first chunk will go in about line 37.

after

class HTML_QuickForm_Rule_Email extends HTML_QuickForm_Rule
 {

but before 
     // switching to a better regex as per CRM-40

Then the second bit you just need to swap

$part = idn_to_ascii($part, 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);
for 
$part = self::idn_to_ascii($part);

If you get any errors after saving just revert to your backup.

Comment: I am new to github. Do I copy the Email.php and replace the one in my server with this copy?

Comment: I've edited the answer above.

Comment: See also discussion at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34023/after-upgrading-to-5-20-0-unable-to-edit-or-enter-contact-email-addresses-em